# How can i rotate a long cylinder object like the rotating thing in the youtube video? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know how I can rotate a long cylinder object, which looks like the rotating thing exactly like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPpcwB7JtBk).

```
void Update() {
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    float x = 4.57 f;
    float y = 0;
    float z = Mathf.Sin(time);
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

That's my script until here and I don't get how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have one main model, with the pivot in the center, and just rotate that with [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html).

```
void Update() {
    transform.Rotate(Time.deltatime,0,0);
}
```

You could also use [`transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

```
void Update(){
    transform.rotation = new Quaternion(transform.rotation.x+Time.deltatime,transform.rotation.y,transform.rotation.z,transform.rotation.w);
}
//Note, I would just put transform.rotation into a new var, to make it easier.
```